# Android Textview setText doesn't show hebrew

Tags: android, textview, hebrew

In my application I have a text view that represents song title, which means it can be filled with titles in different languages. I'm having a strange problem : 
When I do `myTextView.setText("שלום")` it won't show anything.
But if I do the same in the xml file (as text property) it does show the text ?

Comment: A stupid question - you are doing `myTextView.setText("שלום")` instead of `myTextView.setText(שלום)`, right?

Comment: @Zabri yeah of course, thanks I'll edit that in the question

Comment: Well, I tried it and it works fine both on the emulator (4.2.2) and my phone (4.0.3). So I don't know where the problem is. The only things worth mentioning are the weird cursor behaviour on this right-to-left text and also that it made me save the file as UTF-8 instead of Windows-1250.

Comment: @Zabri I'm getting the title from the server (in the right encoding) so saving the file is not it. And the funny thing is that there is another place in the app where the text does show

Comment: Then it seems like the problem has to be somewhere else... Aren't you setting some special attributes to either of the `TextView`s?

Answer (score 6):

Found the problem, I had an attribute of `android:singleLine="true"` and it didn't work fine with hebrew

Comment: Is there any way to overcome this, yet still having singleLine ? I've noticed that using android:maxLines="1" android:minLines="1" seems to work. Does it do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

for me the problem was messing with line spacing -

```
textView.setLineSpacing(0,0);
```

just in case it will help someone